# A/B test options at the widget level

Tags: widgets, testing, split

I am looking for a method to show 1 of 3 different widgets on my site's homepage. I could do this with javascript, but this would increase page weight and I would rather do it at time of render (native wp or php solution).

The solution does not have to be a true A/B test (the selected widget does not have to stay persistent to the user's IP).

What are my options to render a single widget from a range of available widgets?

Edit (clarification) - 
On page load, I want a single widget to display from an array (list) of widgets.  For example, within the 'hero' widget area of my homepage, I want to display a single widget - [image rotator, featured post slider, or map] when a use visits the homepage.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more carefully? I am nto sure exactly what you are asking (though it sounds like you might be trying to make widgets do something they are not meant to do). Are the widgets to be selected from the backend? Are you just randomizing 3 widgets? What?

Comment: way too broad as it is being asked right now. I can probablt think of 4 different ways before my first coffee.

Comment: How do you want to determine _which_ three widgets to rotate? Will it ever be more/less than three? Will they ever be mixed with other non-rotating widgets in same sidebar?

Comment: @MarkKaplun   - updated for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy using the [`sidebars_widget`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sidebars_widgets/) filter.

What we want to do is, in the back end, add our three widgets in the desired sidebar where we need them. This will, as always, display all the widgets in the order they appear in the backend in the sidebar.

If you only need this on the homepage, it is really wise registering a sidebar and then conditionally (*`is_home()`*) includes it in your template.

Anyways, we will now use the `sidebars_widget` filter to randomly remove two of the three sidebars we have added. This will leave you with a random single widget. It must however be noted, you might have the same widget displaying on a new page load as anything random cannot be controlled. Out of three numbers, choosing two randomly, there will always be the possibility that the same two numbers might be chosen again. If you need more control over this, you would need to alter that specific piece of code and somehow implement another more reliable system to handle this

Here is the code, I have commented it so you can follow it easily and also modify as needed. Just note, change `sidebar-2` to the exact **ID** of the sidebar you need to target

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', function ( $sidebars_widgets )
{
    // Return our filter when we are on admin screen
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $sidebars_widgets;

    /**
     * We only want to target only the homepage, so return if it is not homepage
     * You would want to register the sidebar also only on the homepage, otherwise you would
     * need to extend the function to remove the widgets on any other page
     */
    if ( !is_home() )
        return $sidebars_widgets;

    // The ID of the sidebar you want to target
    $sidebar_id_to_target = 'sidebar-2';

    foreach ( $sidebars_widgets as $key=>$sidebars_widget ) {
        // Skip a sidebar if it it isn't our $sidebar_id_to_target
        if ( $key != $sidebar_id_to_target )
            continue;

        // Count the amount of widgets in the desired sidebar
        $counter = count( $sidebars_widget );

        // If the count is 0 or 1, return early
        if ( $counter <= 1 )
            break;

        /**
         * We now want to select a random widget, which will be a random array key
         * We would also need to unset the other two
         */
        $random_numbers = array_rand( range( 0, ( $counter - 1 ) ), ( $counter - 1 ) );
        foreach ( $random_numbers as $random_number )
            unset( $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id_to_target][$random_number] );
    }

    return $sidebars_widgets;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was a method to doing this in php similar to javascript. Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure, glad my answer helped. Enjoy ;-)